# Zero equals one?

Tags: trigonometry, paradoxes

By using inverse trig identities, it can be shown that $sec(x)*cos(x)=1$. However, when $x=π/2$, the resulting function would be $$(1/0)*(0/1)=1,$$ and cross multiplying yields $$1*0=1.$$ I'm not sure where I went wrong in this example but there doesn't seem to be any apparent gaps in the graph of $sec(x)*cos(x)$. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: $\sec(\pi/2)$ is not defined.

Comment: What you are doing wrong is plugging in $x=\pi/2$ while LHS of $\sec x\cos x=1$ isn't defined there.

Comment: $\sec x$ is not defined at $x= \frac{\pi}{2}.$

Comment: Can it not be defined as 1/0? It's the inverse of cos(π/2) which is 0/1.

Comment: The problem is that it is division by zero.  You can not divide by zero and expect good things to happen.

Comment: It cannot be defined as $\frac10$, since that's not a valid fraction.

Comment: If you haven't learned yet that 1/0 is undefined and it is not valid to do any operation involving 1/0 learn it **!!NOW!!**.  By the very fact that you got 1/0 should *immediately* tell you where you went wrong.  You got 1/0 and that is the *END* of any possibility of any reasonable result.  When you get a n = something other than n paradox, the first thing you should look for is did you divide by zero somewhere. (I'd say 3/4 of these paradoxed divide by 0 somewhere.)  In short 1*0 = 1*0 so 1 = (1/0)*0 = 0.  It **NEVER** acceptable to divide by 0.  *EVER*.

Comment: "Can it (sec pi/2) not be defined as 1/0?"  That is *precisely* why sec pi/2 is not defined.  Because it *would* be 1/0.  1/0 is *NOT* an acceptable value.  Ever!  Ever! Ever!  Stand in the corner and write 1000 times "I can NEVER divide by 0 and *NOTHING* is allowed to equal 1/0" on the blackboard.

Comment: Why is this getting downvoted? Though naïve, this is a perfectly valid question, and the OP has clearly demonstrated that he/she has put thought into it.

Comment: It shouldn't be downvoted and we shouldn't insult naive people.  I probably shouldn't yell at them either.  But I do get emphatic about basic points.

Comment: "By using trig identities we can show that $\sec x \cos x=1.$"  NO. We cannot.We can only show this for $\cos x\ne 0$.......... $\sec x$ is defined to be $1/\cos x$ when $\cos x \ne 0$. And $\sec x$ does not exist when $\cos x=0.$

Answer (score 5):

1. The domain of $\sec x$ does not include $\frac{\pi}{2}$; $\sec\frac{\pi}{2}$ is not defined. More information [here](http://www.analyzemath.com/trigonometry/properties.html).
2. Even if you didn't know that, or forgot it, $\frac{1}{0}$ is not defined.
3. Even if you forgot those things, 
   $0\cdot\frac{1}{0} = \frac{0}{0}$
   by your logic, which is undefined.

Answer (score 1):

The terms $1/0,0/0,\infty$ are indeterminate or undefined and cant be used for algebra eg $6\times 0=5\times 0$ cancelling zero we get $6=5$ so you get why they cant be used !

Comment: @cr3 i have edited

Comment: @ArchisWelankar Its nice .

Comment: $\infty$ by itself is not indeterminate nor undefined, but you're right that it can't be used for algebra because it's not a number.

Comment: Thanks @ Tesla and yes that was my motive algebraically useless numbers @ cr3

Comment: You could just say "Undefined terms like $1/0$, indeterminate terms like $0/0$ and not actual numbers like $\infty$ can't be used..." rather than mislabel $\infty$ as indeterminate or undefined.

Answer (score 0):

$m$ divided by $n$ is the specific number, $q$, such that $qn = m$.  So $m$ divided by $0$ is the specific number, $q$, such that $q*0 = m$.  There is no such number so division by 0 is impossible and 1/0 is undefined.

Now, trigonometry. You have a unit circle.  You have an angle $\theta$.  The points on the unit circle corresponding to the angle $\theta$ are $(x, y) = (\cos \theta, \sin \theta)$ and there is an inscribed right triangle corresponding to that angle with sides $x = \cos \theta$, $y = \sin \theta$ and hypotenuse = 1.  That's basic.

So... Draw a tangent line from the (x,y) point that is tangent to the circle.  Extend that line until it crosses the x-axis **(!!Warning!! !!Warning!! Who ever told you it *would* cross the x-axis?)**  *(Oh, shut up, voice in my head; most lines will cross the x-axis.)*... extend that line until it crosses the x-axis.  This forms another right angle that is similar to the first.  The tangent line from $(x,y)$ to the x-axis coresponds to the $x = \cos \theta$ side of the first triangle.  The radius of the unit circle (from the origin to $(x,y)$) on the new triangle corresponds with the  $y = \sin \theta$ side of the original triangle. The x-axis from the origin to where the line intersects the x-axis corresponds to the hypotenuse of the original triangle.

Doing a bit of geometry with realize the scaling factor of this new triangle is $1/\cos \theta$.  So the distance of the tangent point to the x-axis is $\sin \theta /\cos \theta$.  We call that $\tan \theta$ (because it's the length of a tangent chord!!!).  And the length from the $(0,0)$ origin to where the tangent line intersects the x-axis is $1/\cos \theta$.  We call that $\sec \theta$ (because it is the length of a secant chord !... wait, what the heck is a "secant chord"?  .. ).

Let me repeat that as I'm sure your eyes are glazing over.

## $\sec \theta$ is the distance from the origin to where the tangent line intersects the x-axis.

Okay, so let $\theta = \pi/2$.  $\sec \pi/2$ is the distance from the origin to where the tangent line intersects the x-axis.  *But the tangent line is* **parallel** *to the x-axis*!!!!  The tangent line *never* intersects the x-axis and there is no such distance!

*(Maybe I should have listened to that voice in my head.  Wouldn't be the first time.  Of course, there was the time when it told me to... well, never mind.)*

So $\sec \pi/2$ is undefined.

Just like $1/0$ is undefined.

=====

There are many similarities.  $\sec \theta = 1/\cos \theta$ so $\sec \pi/2$ *would* $= 1/0$ if such a thing were possible.

Also notice as $\theta$ gets closer and closer to $\pi/2$ the tangent line gets larger and larger and $\sec \theta$ gets larger and larger and approaches infinity.

Likewise if you are dividing $m$ by $n$ and $n$ gets smaller and smaller and closer to 0 then $m/n$ gets larger and approaches infinity.